# SH - Replace words in text value by variables

Tags: bash, sh

I have a problem that I am not able to solve, i need replace values of text variable in sh by the value of local variables.
Example:

```
~/Documents$ VERSION=1.0.0
~/Documents$ TEST='This is a test, VERSION: $VERSION'
~/Documents$ echo $TEST
This is a test, VERSION: $VERSION
```

I would like to transform the TEST string so that it uses the values ​​of the local variables.
**I know I could change the ' ' to " " and that would work, but in my problem I get a literal string so I can't just do that.**

**Edit**:
I am trying to convert a literal string into a string with replacement of values ​​by local variables in words beginning with "$", I could do this with a simple regex but I am looking for a better way, I believe that you should achieve this using only simple SH commands.

Comment: There is no way to make single quotes not quote a string completely verbatim.

Comment: Tangentially, [quote the argument to `echo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) unless you can be completely sure that it does not contain shell metacharacters.

Comment: I am trying to convert a literal string into a string with replacement of values ​​by local variables in words beginning with "$", I could do this with a simple regex but I am looking for a better way.

Comment: I added a new duplicate which hopefully does what you want. Still not sure I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TEST` must be a literal string, you can use [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). These are `bash` docs, but it also works in `sh`:

> `${var/Pattern/Replacement}`:
> First match of `Pattern`, within `var` replaced with `Replacement`.
> If `Replacement` is omitted, then the first match of `Pattern` is replaced by nothing, that is, deleted.
>
> `${var//Pattern/Replacement}`:  Global replacement. All matches of `Pattern`, within `var` replaced with `Replacement`.

For your given example, it would be `${TEST/\$VERSION/$VERSION}`:

```sh
$ VERSION=1.0.0
$ TEST='This is a test, VERSION: $VERSION'
$ echo "${TEST/\$VERSION/$VERSION}"
This is a test, VERSION: 1.0.0
```

The first dollar sign is escaped so the `Pattern` is `\$VERSION` which becomes the literal string "$VERSION". Then its `Replacement` is `$VERSION` which gets interpolated as "1.0.0".

Comment: "I know I could change the '' to "" and that would work, but in my problem I get a literal string so I can't just do that."

I appreciate the help but I get the value as a text, I can't do that

Comment: Sorry you're right, I skimmed too quickly and I guess the mods did too when they closed it.

Comment: You can do this in pure `sh` with parameter substitution. I edited my answer.